# Error notificación android

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.forms, push

Tengo un problema con las notificaciones en android (usando xamarin forms).  Estoy depurando con un dispositivo físico, cuando la aplicación recibe una notificación la muestra sin problema, pero en Visual Studio aparece este error y termina la depuración, y no se como ver porque ocurre o que es lo que pasa, no se si alguien puede ayudar o le ha ocurrido algo parecido

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo parte del código para mostrar la notificación: MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{

    public static Context AppContext;


    #region Singleton
    private static MainActivity instance;

    public static MainActivity GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = new MainActivity();
        }

        return instance;
    }
    #endregion


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        instance =  this;
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
        StartPushService();
        LoadApplication(new App());

    }



    #region Notificaciones


    public static void StartPushService()
    {
        try
        {
            AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));

            if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
            {
                PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
                AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                alarm.Cancel(pintent);
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public static void StopPushService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(PushNotificationService)), 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }


    public void CreateNotification(string title, string desc, string parameters = null)
    {
        Intent startupIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            startupIntent.PutExtra("param", parameters.ToString());
        }

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.Create(this);

        stackBuilder.AddParentStack(Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(MainActivity)));

        stackBuilder.AddNextIntent(startupIntent);

        const int pendingIntentId = 0;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
            stackBuilder.GetPendingIntent(pendingIntentId, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetAutoCancel(true)
            .SetContentTitle(title)
            .SetContentText(desc)
            .SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound)
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon);

        // Build the notification:
        Notification notification = builder.Build();
        notification.Flags = NotificationFlags.AutoCancel;

        // Get the notification manager:
        NotificationManager notificationManager =  GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        // Publish the notification:
        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notification);


    }


    public void dialogNotify(String title, String message)
    {
        var mainActivity = MainActivity.GetInstance();
        mainActivity.RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(mainActivity);
            AlertDialog alert = dlg.Create();
            alert.SetTitle(title);
            alert.SetButton("Aceptar", delegate
            {
                alert.Dismiss();
            });
            alert.SetMessage(message);
            alert.Show();
        });
    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

Comment: dale continuar y la ventana de Salida (Output Window) encontraras mas detalles que puedas darnos para ayudarte a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Jose, es importante agregues mas detalles para solucionar este problema, sigue el consejo de Jesus.